# LSTM model in keras (R) with time-dependent and not time-dependent branches of inputs

Tags: r, lstm, keras, ensemble-learning

I am using `keras` in `R`. I am studying 600 stations. For each station two types of information are available. The first type is time-dependent (time series) consisting of four variables T, E, P, and Q. The second type is not time dependent (non-sequence) consisting of two variables S (slope) and A (area), which are constant for each station.
The objective is to predict the time series of the target variable Q.

What I did so far is that I developed a local LSTM model that took and was trained based on time series of T, E, P from *only one station* and output time series of Q. In this model, I used `generator` as it was applied in [this tutorial](https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2017-12-20-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks/). For this model, I did not use non-series variables. My model worked fine for all stations.

In a second step, I would like to develop a global model that uses and is trained based on information from all stations. To do this, I thought about using non-series variables to distinguish between the stations. I would like to use this global model at the local scale of one station and compare its performance with my initial local model.

To implement the idea, I tried to use the keras's `functional API` considering two branches of inputs: the upstream branch (a `dense layer`) that took non-series data of one station and the second branch (an `lstm layer`) that took time-series data of the data station and then concatenating the two branches and repeat this procedure in a loop for all stations.

Probably it is due to my lack of expertise, but I do not manage to implement this due to the presence of `generators` in the LSTM branch.

I would appreciate if you could explain me how I could do this properly. Many thanks.

Comment: In this forum network design can be discussed. Technical aspects belong to StackOverflow.  
Can you clarify what do you mean by "My model worked fine for all stations."? It works technically? It trains well and returns improving results on validation data of the trained station? It even returns good results for stations that were not used in the training? Did you compare the loss of "validation data of the trained station" vs the loss of "stations that were not used in the training"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Shall I need to re-ask my question on StackOverflow?
Regarding your question, I would like to simply say that the local model worked well regarding the design (technical details) of the model. Then I trained this local general model station by station and  I did not used the model that I trained based on information from station `x` to predict at station `y`. So I did not make the comparison that you described. Did I manage to answer to your question ?

Comment: I don't want to put it as an answer, but I think it would make sense to try the following: Use all 6 features as input to LSTM. Include all stations in the training. The features S and A will be a constant for a given station but overall they are not constant over the entire dataset. I mean repeat S and A for all time steps. I expect that the model learns to distinguish among stations but also leverages on similarities in T, E, P, Q across stations. Also if A and S are similar for 2 stations this will also learn it. Try to train and compare validation loss with the single station model.

Comment: Let me clarify the other point: You actually seem to have 2 questions. The design of your network in theory belongs to here. The way to program it in R with Keras belongs to StackOverflow. I think first you need to figure out how your network should be before asking programming questions.

Comment: Thanks @Manngo. Regarding the design of the model, I also first thought about putting information of all stations together and train the model. To do this, I came to conclusion that I needed to introduce a dummy variable for instance `id` to distinguish between different stations. But I have 600 stations and adding a `dummy` variable of 600 values would add 600 additional columns to my features (If I am not mistaken about how we treat dummy variables).

Comment: @Manngo, I had read that introducing constant variables to the ordinary training of lstm models would pollute the time series. I started to think about another design in which we have two branches of inputs: an upstream branch into which we feed the constant variables and a downstream branch where we introduce time variables. That is why I tried to continue wit this second approach and develop an `API`model with an auxiliary input layer (`layer_embedding`) and a main input LSTM layer and then concatenating the two inputs. Some approach like the one explained [here](http://example.com).

Comment: And yes, from the technical point, since in my local lstm model I used generators I had also some confusion regrading the the dimensions that I had to use in the `input_dim` argument of the `layer_embedding`.

Comment: My concern about your concept with branches (let me call it DAG) is that the LSTM branch will be generalized for the data from all stations. Then the branch with the constant auxiliary input is expected to specialize the LSTM result to the given station. Nevertheless if you want the station ID encoded with one-hot method you still need 600 variables.It's a trial and error process, I think you should try both approaches.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. The problem with one-hot method is that I had already runtime problem for some of my stations with very long time series. 
For the DAG approach, I had some technical problems related to generators to implement the idea. Shall I ask  a new question on stack overflow ? and could I mention you there as well ? Many thanks.

Comment: What is you batch size? You can always reduce it to solve memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Approach #3 from this answer could be relevant/applicable: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/17139

Here, you would condition the first RNN/LSTM cell's hidden state based on your non-sequence features. In theory, this appears to be more elegant and lighter-weight than repeating 'static' variables at every timestep. However, both approaches could work in principle.